# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient

Tags: flutter, crash, geolocation

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.near_by_api_ex, PID: 10222
> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface          com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.ConnectionsClient, but class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.ConnectionsClient' appears in /data/app/com.example.near_by_api_ex-SQmqvcjOXV3emcH2l_ILUw==/base.apk)

Comment: So, no info on what you're doing, did it work before, have you tried to solve it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been some changes in Google's API & versions which are used in Flutter Location Package. We need to wait until they reflect those compatible changes in the package.

PR for that issue:
https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/pull/803

There's a workaround for that. I forked the repo & used it in pubspec but this change is not working in my project.
https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/issues/802#issuecomment-1408420419

Answer (score 4):

Solution Very Easy

1. Open The Project into the Android Studio
2. Location pub library and geolocator pub libary
   same
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'

[image]

Comment: successfully working in my code
Thank you.